# iPhone opengl es: Conceptual knowledge

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Hi guys I have a conceptual question in the render function of opengles on the iPhone. Say I have a cube. The cube has 6 faces and consequently 12 triangles. If I calculate a normal for each triangle I have 12 normals, each normal has x,y,z cordinates. Consequently I have an array of 36 floats. In my render function I want to pass the x,y,z cordinates to the vertex for some lighting related calculations.  This is my call to achieve that

```
  glVertexAttribPointer(_simpleLightNormalAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float), duplicateNormals);
```

The indexes 0,1,2 contain the x,y,z cordinates of the first triangle and so on. How does opengl know that indexes 2,3,4 contain the x,y,z cordinates of the 2 triangle?

Any help would be much appreciated/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL doesn't define a vertex the way you do. In classical fixed-pipeline OpenGL a single vertex is a location and/or a normal and/or a colour and/or a texture coordinate.

So normals associate with vertices, not with polygons. Looking at it another way, if you're supplying normals you generally need to provide each vertex separately for each face that it rests on.

So in the case of a cube, you should supply 24 vertices, in six groups of four. All the vertices in each group will have the same normal but different positions.

Addition:

In ES 2 basically the same rule applies: all properties are per vertex and are interpolated across such faces as you specify. So you're still not really in a position to specify properties per face. The exception to this is that you can change uniforms at will, so in your case you could use a uniform for the normal though you'd end up drawing two triangles, changing the uniform, drawing two more triangles, changing the uniform again, etc, which would be an incredibly inefficient way to proceed.

So you'll probably still need the 24 vertices — one per location per face.

Comment: I am sorry I guess I should have mentioned this before I am using OpenGL Es 2.0 which does not have a fixed but programmable pipeline

Comment: I've updated my answer, but it's basically the same as before — OpenGL applies the vertex shader to transform all vertices, then interpolates any varyings you've specified across the pixels it hence determines need to be painted and hence calls the fragment shader to supply a colour. The vertex shader is called once per vertex not once per face and hence doesn't supply any indication as to which face it's thinking of painting next. Good hardware caches the result of the vertex shader anyway.

Comment: I think I partially understand your answer but there is still some fog in my brain ... I am drawing a cube in triangle strip mode ==> 8 vertices, 12 triangles, 36 indices into the vertex array. Now I want to supply normals to each vertex. I guess my normals array will have to contain 36 normals? All the vertexes belonging to one particular face will have the same value for the normal? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yep, that's right. So if you write a vertex as (pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, norm.x, norm.y, norm.z) and supposing your cube is 2x2x2, axis aligned and centred on the origin you'll have vertices including (-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0), (-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0) and (-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1)

Comment: Ok... Just to confirm the normal information corresponds to the triangles in my indices array ie. The first 3 positions in the normal array are occupied by the normal for triangle described by the vertexes present at position 0,1,2 in the index array?

Comment: You'll probably end up supplying your normal array via `glVertexAttribPointer`, in which case it'll be indexed according to your DrawElements indices exactly as everything else you supply to `glVertexAttribPointer`, such as vertex location. So if 0,1,2 are the first three indices, then the first three normals will be the first, second and third in the array.

Comment: Exactly... In that case the normals present at 0,1,2 will have the same value right? As all the 3 vertices represent the same triangle? Also I had another thought. My next 3 values in the indices array are 2,3,0. Despite this I will store the normals formed by the triangle using the vertices 2,3,0 at the position 3,4,5, in the normals array right?

Comment: I have set my normals to be my destinationColor in vertex shader. I am manually setting the value of each of my normal to 1,0,0. But despite this my cube is black in color. I am sure I am missing a tiny detail but I cannot figure out what?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8463/discussion-between-tommy-and-abhi)

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing each triangle's vertices separately (as the OpenGL Game project does and as you seem to be doing) rather than using indices then you need to specify a normal for each vertex.  For a cube with sharply defined edges you would probably want to send the same perpendicular normal for each vertex on a face.

If you really want/need to specify fewer normals, you should look into using indices.  Then you would define the 8 distinct vertices in the cube, the 8 normals that go with them, and define your triangles using an array of indices for your vertices.  Bear in mind that with this approach you will have multiple faces sharing normals.  This can be a good thing if you are looking for a smooth lighting effect (like with curves) or a bad thing if you want sharp, distinct edges (like with cubes).

Hope this helps

Comment: I guess I would want to pass each triangles vertex separately. Hence I guess I need a normal for each vertex. But herein lies the problem. The normal for each vertex would change depending on which triangle does that vertex lie in. I have calculated the normals for each of the triangles in the cube. My question is how do I store this information and how do I send this info to openGL land?